# Getting marginal effects for lm_robust model relating to two interaction of two factors variables

Tags: r, stata

I used this script to get the margin by using the function margin but it deosn't give the same results as stata
**R script**

```
#### Clustering model
model1<-lm_robust(P~(factor(A)+factor(Y)+factor(W)+factor(T))*factor(V)
                         ,se_type="stata", cluster=ID, data=df)
```

this how df looks like :

```
| ID| A | P | Y | W | T | V |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 5 | 4 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 6 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 8 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | 5 | 4 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
|10 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
|11 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
```

to compute the margin for the interaction of variables A et V i used this scripts

```
v_p0<-cbind(summary(margins(model1, data = subset(df, V == 0),variables = "A")),V="0")
v_p1<-cbind(summary(margins(model1, data = subset(df, V == 1),variables = "A")),V="1")
v_p<-rbind(v_p0,v_p1)
v_p
```

I applied the same model in stata and it give me this for margin
**STATA script and results**

```
reg P i.A i.Y i.W i.T i.V i.V#(i.A i.Y i.W i.T), cluster(ID) robust 
margins A#V
-----------------------------------------------------------

                        |            Delta-method
                        |     Margin   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]

----+----------------------------------------------------------------
A#V                     |
factor(Act1)#factor(V1) |   4.160484   .2378576    17.49   0.000     3.693894    4.627074
factor(Act1)#factor(V2) |    4.66416   .0311782   149.60   0.000        4.603     4.72532
factor(Act2)#factor(V1) |   3.369741    .143861    23.42   0.000     3.087538    3.651943
factor(Act2)#factor(V2) |   3.832591   .0488409    78.47   0.000     3.736783    3.928399
factor(Act3)#factor(V1) |   2.797249   .1519788    18.41   0.000     2.499122    3.095376
factor(Act3)#factor(V2) |   3.401255   .0664888    51.16   0.000     3.270828    3.531682
factor(Act4)#factor(V1) |   2.205923   .1090756    20.22   0.000     1.991956    2.419889
factor(Act4)#factor(V2) |   2.302126   .0699838    32.90   0.000     2.164844    2.439409
factor(Act5)#factor(V1) |   1.536017    .054074    28.41   0.000     1.429943     1.64209
factor(Act5)#factor(V2) |    2.95762   .1925693    15.36   0.000     2.579869    3.335371
```

I try to get marginal for lm_robust model  relating to A:V but i don't get the same result as Stata

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure that you cannot do this with `margins` (maybe with its sister package `predictions`). However, here’s an example where I replicate the Stata results with [the `marginaleffects` package.](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/) (Disclaimer: I am the author.)

Note that the example uses `lm()`, but that the syntax would be identical with `lm_robust()`. Also, instead of using `lm_robust` and loading the `estimatr` package, you could use the `vcov` argument, which should produce identical results.

And here is a side-by-side comparisons with detailed explanations of the main differences between Stata and `marginaleffects`: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/alternative_software.html#stata

```r
library(marginaleffects)

dat <- read.csv("https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/AER/Affairs.csv")
mod <- lm(affairs ~ factor(children) * factor(rating), data = dat)
predictions(
    mod,
    variables = c("children", "rating"),
    by = c("children", "rating"))

           type children rating predicted std.error statistic      p.value
    1  response       no      4 0.7500000 0.4977992 1.5066315 1.319051e-01
    2  response       no      5 0.7395833 0.3213280 2.3016460 2.135514e-02
    3  response       no      3 0.5416667 0.6426560 0.8428563 3.993088e-01
    4  response       no      2 3.5000000 1.1131129 3.1443352 1.664647e-03
    5  response       no      1 4.6666667 1.8177057 2.5673389 1.024824e-02
    6  response      yes      4 1.4545455 0.2537020 5.7332840 9.850452e-09
    7  response      yes      5 0.7058824 0.2699695 2.6146741 8.931262e-03
    8  response      yes      3 1.7391304 0.3790178 4.5885186 4.464026e-06
    9  response      yes      2 3.9827586 0.4133998 9.6341583 5.736016e-22
    10 response      yes      1 3.6923077 0.8731976 4.2284905 2.352645e-05
         conf.low conf.high
    1  -0.2256685  1.725669
    2   0.1097920  1.369375
    3  -0.7179160  1.801249
    4   1.3183388  5.681661
    5   1.1040289  8.229304
    6   0.9572987  1.951792
    7   0.1767518  1.235013
    8   0.9962691  2.481992
    9   3.1725100  4.793007
    10  1.9808719  5.403744
```

And here’s the Stata output for reference. Note that `marginaleffects` and Stata produce numerically identical estimates and standard errors, but that `marginaleffects` uses Z-stat instead of t-stat, which explains the slight differences in confidence intervals and p values.

```
. import delimited https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/AER/Affairs.csv
. encode children, gen(child)
. quiet reg affairs i.child##i.rating
. margins child#rating

Adjusted predictions                                       Number of obs = 601
Model VCE: OLS

Expression: Linear prediction, predict()

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
child#rating |
       no#1  |   4.666667   1.817706     2.57   0.010     1.096718    8.236615
       no#2  |        3.5   1.113113     3.14   0.002     1.313862    5.686138
       no#3  |   .5416667    .642656     0.84   0.400    -.7205008    1.803834
       no#4  |        .75   .4977992     1.51   0.132    -.2276707    1.727671
       no#5  |   .7395833    .321328     2.30   0.022     .1084996    1.370667
      yes#1  |   3.692308   .8731976     4.23   0.000      1.97736    5.407256
      yes#2  |   3.982759   .4133998     9.63   0.000     3.170847     4.79467
      yes#3  |    1.73913   .3790178     4.59   0.000     .9947447    2.483516
      yes#4  |   1.454545    .253702     5.73   0.000     .9562783    1.952813
      yes#5  |   .7058824   .2699695     2.61   0.009      .175666    1.236099
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Final note: The code you showed us for Stata was to compute "marginal predictions" or "marginal means" and NOT "marginal effects". Please see the `marginaleffects` package vignette for definitions of those quantities.